# Content type / Document Set

Tags: sharepoint, content-type, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to create a Content Type in another Content Type ?
Content type I want to use is 'Document Set

> DocSet A
>
> > DocSet B
> >
> > > Folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, every new content type inherits from a parent content type.

Here is a link with specific steps to what you are trying to do:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-configure-a-new-Document-Set-content-type-9db6d6dc-c23a-4dcd-a359-3e4bbbc47fc1#__toc252543682